# disable column on post and user list

Tags: posts, pages, taxonomy, users

I'm looking for the way to disable user column (posts and role) from users list. like you see in the picture 
[image]

I'm also search how to disable column author on page list (in red on the picture)
[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`manage_{$screen->id}_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_-screen-id-_columns/) hooks for this.

To manage user columns we can use `manage_users_columns` which is passed an array of columns and whatever we don't want we can [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```
/**
 * Manage User Admin Display Table Columns
 *
 * @param Array $columns
 *      [cb]        => <input type="checkbox" />
 *      [username]  => Username
 *      [name]      => Name
 *      [email]     => Email
 *      [role]      => Role
 *      [posts]     => Posts
 *
 * @return Array $columns
 */
function wpseq_270133_users( $columns ) {

    unset( $columns['role'] );
    unset( $columns['posts'] );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'wpseq_270133_users' );
```

Pages is a very similar fashion but instead of a `users` hook we need to specify `pages`:

```
/**
 * Manage Pages Admin Display Table Columns
 *
 * @param Array $columns
 *      [cb]        => <input type="checkbox" />
 *      [title]     => Title
 *      [author]    => Author
 *      [date]      => Date
 *
 * @return Array $columns
 */
function wpseq_270133_pages( $columns ) {

    unset( $columns['author'] );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns', 'wpseq_270133_pages' );
```

---

There's also checkboxes under Screen Options to remove these columns for yourself whenever logged in, the above code will hide these columns from every role.

[image: Screen Options Open]